# Image not showing up on Html

Tags: html, notepad

I'm completely new to HTML and am trying to code my first thing using Notepad. I put the thing for an image to show up but it won't. what am I doing wrong? I've written the code below and I put the part I'm having trouble with in bold.

I tried to make the image show up but it didn't work.

```html
<body>
  <h1>My First Heading</h1>

  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vk4KK-gh0FM&pp=ygUObm9raWEgcmluZ3RvbmU%3D"> Iphone </a> **
  <img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:IPhone_14_Pro_vector_(blue).svg" width="500" height="600">**
</body>
```

Comment: Step one in a case like this is to see if the URL loads independently. [Try it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:IPhone_14_Pro_vector_(blue).svg).

Answer (score 2):

The URL you're using is for a web page, not an image.

This is the actual image URL:  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/IPhone_14_Pro_vector_%28blue%29.svg

Comment: Thank you for the answer! it seems to work when I put it instead of the current one. But how is that link different from the one I put? Also where did you get it from?

Comment: @dban2017 Go to the URL you originally had.  You'll see it loads a web page.  Click "original image"... and see that you get the image.

Answer (score 0):

your URL is directing to the webpage itself, not the image.

I believe this should be the URL placed on the `src`:
**https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/IPhone_14_Pro_vector_%28blue%29.svg/295px-IPhone_14_Pro_vector_%28blue%29.svg.png**